# Tenses after "when," "if," "before," "after," and "as soon as"

Tags: tense

What tenses should I use after these adverbs, Present Simple or Present Perfect? Is it possible to use the Future Simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Present perfect conveys a sense of the end of the action, whereas present simple conveys a sense of the beginning or middle. For example,

```
As soon as I have eaten, I will help you with that.

As soon as I eat, my stomach starts grumbling.
```

The first sentence refers to once the eating is done, but the second sentence refers to when the eating starts. Simple future is never used here.

Answer (score 5):

1. In the context you appear to be asking about, none of these words acts as an *adverb*. *If* is a conjunction, while *before*, *after* and *as soon as* are prepositions.
2. Depending on circumstances, both simple present and present perfect may be used with any of these.

   > If I understand you correctly, I disagree.
   >   If I have understood you correctly, I disagree.
   >
   > I will send you the paper before I finish it.
   >   I will send you the paper before I have finished it.
   >
   > I will send you the paper after I finish it.
   >   I will send you the paper after I have finished it.
   >
   > I will send you the paper as soon as I find it.
   >   I will send you the paper as soon as I have found it.
3. What you call "simple future", the construction with *WILL* + bare
   infinitive, is not ordinarily used with any of these in a *futurive*
   sense. On occasion, you may find *will* employed in place of the
   more usual *do* after the prepositions when **a)** the prepositional
   clause follows a main clause with *will* **AND b)** the infinitive
   which complements *will* in the prepositional clause is omitted:

   > I will finish before/after/as soon as you will *... representing*
   >   I will finish before/after/as soon as you finish.

   Moreover, this construction is also used in what is called a *volitional* sense, signifying "willingness". In this sense it may be used with *if*:

   > I'll be happy to come if you will pay my expenses.