# Why does this sentence use "have had" (present perfect) instead of just "had" (past)?

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect

I am currently learning english for my CAE exam.
I stumbled across this sentence:

> As soon as I *have had* a look at the designs, I will send them to you.

Why is it *have had* in this case and not just *had*?
I thought present perfect is used for recent indefinite actions or habits but none of those apply here.

Comment: Does this sound alright to you? "**As soon as** I had a look..." when talking about the future?

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/8083/tenses-after-when-if-before-after-and-as-soon-as

Comment: Perhaps you're being throw off because of the phrasal verb *have a look*.  If you replace it with *look* does it seem simpler?  Compare "As soon as I have looked at the designs, I will send them" and "As soon as I looked at the designs, I will send them"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"As soon as I had a look..." would imply you're describing something that happened in the past, ie, "As soon as I had a look, I sent them the designs."

Since the action you describe will take place in the future, but is already completed by the time you are sending the designs, that is, you *have* had a look, you use the present perfect.

If you add the word 'after' in the sentence...

> "*After* I have had a look at the designs, I will send them to you."

...this distinction becomes clearer. In this case you could also omit "have had" altogether and the meaning would stay the same.

Comment: thank you buddy

Answer (score 2):

The present perfect form is used here to stress the *'finishedness'* of the action.